# React router history.push in useEffect, two renders

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Why does the App component render twice every time location changes?

Idea here is that when location or language changes the useEffect callback will add matching query string to the url.

```
const App = () => {
  const history = useHistory()
  const loc = useLocation()
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState("en")

  useEffect(() => {
    history.push({pathname: window.location.pathname, search: '?lang=' + language})
  }, [language, loc.pathname])

  return(Some components here)
```

Comment: remove loc.pathname from second argument in useEffect

Answer (score 0):

You're updating your location which is one of the values in the dependency array of the useEffect. This is what's causing the double render.

If you want to avoid this, try storing the previous location in a ref and compare the two before the history.push